# Can't create nested struct in Playground with more than 3 variables

Tags: swift, xcode, struct, swift-playground

Im new with playground and Im having this weird problem:

**error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff28405c40).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.**

Code:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport


struct Object {
    
    let id: String
    let locations: Locations
    
    struct Coordinates {
        let x: Int
        let y: Int
    }
    
    struct Locations {
        let fr: Coordinates?
        let en: Coordinates?
        let br: Coordinates?
        let jp: Coordinates?
        let ee: Coordinates?
        
    }
}

let object = Object(id: "123", locations: Object.Locations(fr: Object.Coordinates(x: 1, y: 1), << CRASH
                                                          en: Object.Coordinates(x: 1, y: 1),
                                                          br: Object.Coordinates(x: 1, y: 1),
                                                          jp: Object.Coordinates(x: 1, y: 1),
                                                          ee: Object.Coordinates(x: 1, y: 1)))
```

The weird part is that if I remove few variables from Locations struct (lets say I leave only 3) everything works fine. What gives?

Comment: try it with a macOS playground instead of iOS

Comment: It works! wow... Thanks!